# Use opencv + gstreamer to have multiple(e.g more than 1) appsink for different post processing

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

I tried to use OpenCV and Gstreamer to achieve that 1 input video source, get 2 appsink for later processing. The following is the code I tried with "tee" but cannot work as I expected...

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('filesrc location={} ! mpeg4videoparse ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! queue ! nvvidconv ! tee name=t t. ! nvvidconv ! queue ! appsink t. ! nvvidconv ! queue ! appsink'.format(video_path), cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

What I expect is like,

```
cap0, cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture('filesrc location={} ! mpeg4videoparse ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! queue ! nvvidconv ! tee name=t t. ! nvvidconv ! queue ! appsink t. ! nvvidconv ! queue ! appsink'.format(video_path), cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

Is this possible? I want to make 1 input video source to have different processing afterward, that is why I want to make it two outputs like cap0, cap1... Any comments?

Comment: from one VideoCapture? not like that. -- make a thread that reads from the device and keeps the latest frame around. "producer/consumer" pattern... if you truly have two separate consumers. usually you can just take one frame and call two different functions. you can copy numpy arrays (frames) before you change them.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for your comments. How about multiple video sources? Is that could be more efficient by 1 gstreamer pipeline? Or use two pipeline for each video streamer will be the same?

Comment: @EdwardChang, you may better explain your case (how many sources, cameras with fiexed resolution/framerate or reading from various resolution files) and your final goal for better advice. For using several sources, you would just use 2 opencv VideoCaptures, each one running its won pipeline. I don't think there is much you can gain on ressource usage using the same pipeline.

Comment: Also note that your pipeline lacks decoding, so better try in single case: `cap = cv2.VideoCapture('filesrc location={} ! decodebin ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,fomat=BGR ! appsink drop=1`.

Comment: You can also try, if your sources have fixed resolution and have at least same width or height, to compose these with compositor or nvcompositor, receive the concatenated frame as single opencv source, then crop with opencv for each source, but not sure that would be better for your case. There might be other soiutions such as using src pad probes in gstreamer to get buffers, but this would be more complex, so better tell your real case.